# Sign in using twitter

Tags: twitter, authentication, oauth, twitter-oauth

I want to add sign in using twitter functionality in my website. I have already added sign in using facebook and google functionality in my website. In Facebook and google we can load the javascript SDK asynchronously and then its login button code handles everything but in twitter there is no such support. I am not able to understand which  libraries to use and how to use them.
Please suggest me which way can I implement this sign in using twitter in my website.

Comment: Same here: I have already added facebook and google sign in, now I would like to to the same with twitter but I don't understand how to do it... Can you help me please?

Comment: @neoDev Use Twitter4j
http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html

Comment: I will try it very soon, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally used Twitter4j and it is working well uptil now.